# Centos 6.6 CURL returns error when connecting to some SSL Site

Tags: php, linux, ssl, curl, centos

I already tried to search most of things here but seems not worked.
tried to curl -I -v https://secure2.lionair.co.id/lionairibe/OnlineBooking.aspx returns error usually im using ubuntu server and do not have any issue with this, but when i tried to use centos 6.6 suddenly all my curls to https returns that error both in PHP or even with linux command line
appreciate if you can help me

Response when tried to curl :

```
* About to connect() to secure2.lionair.co.id port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 202.79.216.183... connected
* Connected to secure2.lionair.co.id (202.79.216.183) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -12190
* Error in TLS handshake, trying SSLv3...
> HEAD /lionairibe/OnlineBooking.aspx HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: secure2.lionair.co.id
> Accept: */*
>
* Connection died, retrying a fresh connect
* Closing connection #0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://secure2.lionair.co.id/lionairibe/OnlineBooking.aspx'
* About to connect() to secure2.lionair.co.id port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 202.79.216.183... connected
* Connected to secure2.lionair.co.id (202.79.216.183) port 443 (#0)
* TLS disabled due to previous handshake failure
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -12190
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

Thanks :)

Comment: [12190](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ref/ssl/sslerr.html) refers to an unsupported protocol version. Check which variants your server supports, then use a specific option such as `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2` if your build supports it.

Comment: how do i check it? since im not expertise in linux

Comment: Upgrading the nss package might also help (like `yum update nss`).

Comment: I had the same problem using `libcurl`. Updating `curl` and `libcurl` to version 7.19.7-53.el6_9 on CentOS 6.7 SOLVED the problem. Just in case, I also updated `nss` to 3.28.4-4.el6_9. Everything from standard `@updates` repository (http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/updates/)

Comment: // , Can you show us the research you did before posting this?

Answer (score 2):

The server supports only TLS 1.1, i.e. no SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2. So you have to be really careful when talking to this strange server. I don't know if the version of curl your are using already supports the necessary options to restrict the TLS protocol this way and if this option is implemented for the NSS backend, but you might try to enforce TLS 1.1 this way:

```
 curl  --tlsv1.1 https://secure2.lionair.co.id
```

If this does not help you might need to upgrade curl, use curl with another backend (like OpenSSL) or use tools like wget instead.